# Is there a phrase/word meaning "visit a place for a short period of time"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I feel like I have heard "*come spin to my place*" being used in this meaning but I wasn't able to find similar sentences on the web.

Answer (score 19):

I would think ***pop in*** describes a short visit, as [Free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pop+in#:%7E:text=Verb,for%20a%20quick%20coffee%20break%22) indicates:

> `enter briefly`
>
> He popped in for two minutes.

Here is what [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pop-in-into-somewhere) says:

> `to visit briefly:`
>
> Why don’t you pop in and see us this afternoon?

Comment: In "Seinfeld" a pop-in is an unannounced visit

Comment: "Pop in" strikes me (as a British person myself) as being quite a British expression. Is that the case?

Comment: Well, if you check the [American heritage dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=pop), you will find this definition at the "pop in" entry: `To visit briefly: just popped in to say hello.` So I don't think it is only BrE. But when I checked [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pop+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpop%20in%3B%2Cc0) comparing BrE and AmE, I found that BrE uses it more.

Answer (score 10):

American speaker.

- dropped in for a few minutes
- quickly stopped by
- grab something from {location}
- come pick me up
- pick up something from {location}

> I need to pick up my sister from work.

This could include going inside or not.

I've never heard "spin to my place" before. Probably regional.

Comment: In Texas, I'd say "drop by".

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- same, that or "swing by my place" are pretty much used interchangeably for me.

Comment: I've used both "drop by" and "swing by". I've never heard "spin by" though.

Answer (score 4):

"Have a spin" or "go out for a spin" is a rather old fashion way for "go on a short pleasure trip in/on a vehicle".  For short visit (in addition to other good suggestions) perhaps "drop by"

> I dropped by my uncle on Friday, and he took me for a spin in his new car.

I suppose "Spin by your place" (as suggested in comments) would fit,  as suggesting that "I will stop briefly while taking a short trip in a vehicle"

Comment: *jaunt* /jônt/ noun (verb) : (go on) a short excursion or journey for pleasure.

Comment: "… [spin by your place](https://books.google.it/books?id=A9rskuuA0RwC&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90&dq=%22spin+by+your+place%22&source=bl&ots=CvZI6AjmzV&sig=ACfU3U1E3JPJF044JGCkpxCJyfwf42u3vw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVr4Tdrf3tAhVk0uAKHWipDP8Q6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22spin%20by%20your%20place%22&f=false)" would also fit, admittedly not a very common turn of phrase. Oops, the same type of comment was left under the OP.

Answer (score 3):

**pitstop** - often used when travelling, particularly when stopping to get gas, use the restroom, or eat food.

> We're running low on gas. Let's make a pitstop at the next exit.

From Google Dictionary:

> noun **pitstop**
>
> 1. a stop in the pits for servicing and refueling, especially during a race.
> 2. a brief rest, especially during a journey.

---

"**layover**", "**stop over**" - also common when travelling, especially when the stay is a bit longer or even overnight.

> Let's stop over in Chicago and then head north in the morning.
> Allen knows a lot of great places to stop over while we're biking through Europe.
> The only flight left has a five-hour layover in New York.

"Layover" is a real word, but "stop over" is more of a regional phrase that means the same thing.

From Google Dictionary:

> noun **layover**; plural noun layovers
>
> 1. a period of rest or waiting before a further stage in a journey.

---

**pop**, **drop**, and **stop** can all be used interchangeably with "**by**", "**in**", and "**off**" when referring to a short visit, typically less than 2 hours.

> I'll drop by the next time I'm in town.
> I stopped by Jim's place on the way home.
> Feel free to drop in any time!
> I just wanted to pop in and say hi.
> Frank's been here four hours... I thought he said he was just going to pop by?
> Don't even think about stopping off at the pub tonight!

---

"**in and out**" - common phrase when running errands.

> Can we stop by the store on the way home? I'll just be in and out, I promise.

Comment: There is also "pop around" or "pop round" if you are British or Australian

Comment: As a non-native I've heard "drop/stop by" the most.

Answer (score 3):

Come swing by my place, and I might suggest some other idioms.

Answer (score 3):

"Spin by", as in "Come spin by my place" sounds more natural to my American ear.

I found several web hits under ["spin by my"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spin%20by%20my%22) or ["come spin by"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22come%20spin%20by%22).

In this case, "by" indicates more of a quick diversion along a journey, rather than a terminal destination.

Answer (score 2):

The perfect word (in my opinion) for a brief stay at a place is *sojourn*.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sojourn

> a short period when a person stays in a particular place:

> My **sojourn** in the youth hostel was thankfully short.

> After a brief **sojourn** in Holland to study Sanskrit, he moved to India.

It is often used with adjectives like "short" or "brief" to further emphasise the brevity of the visit or stay.

Note that this word is perfect for describing a temporary visit to a location (which can be a hotel, a friend's house, another country, etc.) but not really appropriate for running an errand at a grocery store, for example.

Comment: Note that **sojourn** is quite an old fashioned word. Many native English speakers would  not be completely sure what it meant.

Comment: Sojourn is the very first word I thought of

Comment: The only context I've ever heard it used is the Passover Seder.

Comment: If you use this in the U.S., the most likely result is that 1) people will think you are quoting some Bible verse, and 2) they won't really understand what you mean, but will be too embarrassed to admit it by asking you to clarify.

Comment: It's interesting that the definition says it implies briefness, yet the example sentences feel the need to directly state the shortness or briefness

Comment: This works when wearing a smoking jacket and monocle

Answer (score 1):

A **whistle-stop** is a very short visit. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/whistle-stop) has

> **whistle-stop**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> Very fast and with only brief pauses.
> *He enjoyed a whistle-stop tour of the deanery during which he met all the Anglican clergy.*

So you could make a whistle-stop at your friend's house on your way to...

Comment: "whistle-stop" is, as your source indicates, an adjective. So one cannot make "a whistle-stop"

Comment: @JudyN. my source also gives it as a noun, with the usage more clearly in [MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/whistle-stop-tour?q=whistle+stop)

Comment: You appear to have linked to the entry for "whistle-stop tour"

Comment: @JudyN. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/whistle-stop) specifically says "Noun (as modifier): a whistle-stop tour", and "a brief appearance".

Comment: _"a whistle-stop tour"_ is an example, not a definition, hence why it's in italics; that is, "whistle-stop" can appear as part of a noun when it modifies another word, such as tour.

Comment: You're right that it gives the sense of "a brief appearance in a town", but my feeling of the context of this is more a situation where _many_ stops are being made in succession. I don't think a single stop would be "a whistle-stop" (– not that I would ever use it in this sense to begin with) as it gives the impression you are eager to get to the _next_ stop

Comment: If I am not mistaken a whistle-stop was originally a place where a train stopped only at need, as to drop a passenger, or to take on fuel or water, but where there was no scheduled stop. Thus any stop at such a place was as brief as possible. From this came the sense of a very brief stop, and from this the adjective senses.

Answer (score 1):

"Come on by (for a bit)?"

"Stop by"

Answer (score 0):

-> **to pay a visit**

It does not imply that the visitor keeps lingering there.

From the [free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pay+a+visit):

> pay a visit
>
> pay (someone or something) a visit
>
> To visit someone or something.
>
> We need to pay Grandma a visit and see how her trip to Florida was.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].

Answer (score -1):

"sojourn" can be used. It literally means 'a temporary stay'

examples:

1. Your sojourn to this place is most welcome.
2. A sojourn to London on our way to Paris will a good decision.